# How do I load an image into the img tag from a python field?

Tags: html, django, django-models, jinja2

I am currently loading an object in HTML using `jinja` as follows

```
<span> {{ object.name }} </span>
<img src = "{{ object.image }}" >
```

The `image` field is an `ImageField` in the database. The image URL looks like this

```
http://127.0.0.1:8000/uploads/testimage.png
```

How do I render the image correctly in the `<img>` tag?

Comment: `<img src="{{ object.image.url }}" >`

Comment: It returns the following issue: `The 'image' attribute has no file associated with it.`

Comment: then you need to guard the image such that it only renders if `object.image` is truthful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> The image URL looks like this
>
> ```
> http://127.0.0.1:8000/uploads/testimage.png
> ```

This is *not* the image URL, this `{{ object.image }}` renders the path to the image in the media directory you specified. But there is (likely) no view listening to this view.

In order to render the images, you use the `.url` attribute of the `FieldFile` object, so:

```
<span> {{ object.name }} </span>
{% if object.image %}<img src="{{ object.image.url }}">{% endif %}
```

You should furthermore configure the `urls.py` to handle a request to these media files. This is explained in [the *serving files uploaded by a user during development* section of the documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/howto/static-files/#serving-files-uploaded-by-a-user-during-development):

```
from django.conf import settings
from django.conf.urls.static import static

urlpatterns = [
    # …
] + static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
```

Note that Django does *not* serve media/static files in production. You will in that case need to configure the webserver like nginx/apache/…